# Teradata SQL: covert timestamp into format 'dd.mm.yyyyBhh:mi:ss.s(6)'

Tags: sql, teradata

in which format should I convert timestamp to receive timestamp value like this `15.08.2017 22:17:41.860000`

?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, you just need to Cast it to a string after adding the format:

```
Cast(Cast(tscol AS FORMAT 'dd.mm.yyyyBhh:mi:ss.s(6)')  AS CHAR(26))
```

Or shorter using

```
To_Char(tscol,'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ssff')
```

Comment: Thanks! and is it possible to get timestamp value ? (not char)

Comment: A timestamp is stored in an internal format, how it's displayed is usually controlled by the client. Dependig on your client you might be able it modify it, but this is not recommended as a timestamp literal (e.g. used in WHERE) uses international standard `timestamp 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'`, similar for `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'` and `time 'hh:mi:ss'`